# Reading the sum of ASCII of each word in a sentence

Tags: c#, .net

i am new to c#. I am writing a c# function that read the sum of ASCII of each word in a sentence.

Below is my code. There are problems when i convent each char to integer.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char[] chars = {' ','\r','\n'};
    string[] str = textBox1.Text.Split(chars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int[] sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {

        int[] asciiChar = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(str[i]); // error occurs here.
        sum[i] = asciiChar.Sum();

    }
    label1.Text = sum.Length.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Help with _what_? You forgot to describe your actual issue.

Comment: What error occurs there?

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.Encoding.GetChars(byte[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: AND Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'byte[]

Answer (score 4):

`GetChars` expects to receive a `byte[]`. But you are passing a `string`. You should be calling [`GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx) instead.

```
byte[] asciiChar = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str[i]);
```

Also, you forgot to allocate the array `sum`.

Comment: Hey David, thanks. But i got another problem.

Error 1 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Sum(System.Linq.IQueryable<int>)' has some invalid arguments

Error 2 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>'

It seems that i can use .sum() for a byte variable. And it cant convert from 'byte[]' to integer ~

Comment: I'd write my own extension method to Sum the contents of a byte[]. I think I answered the original question.

Comment: I have changed the code, and there are no build error now. But run time error occur. How come there are so many error. OMG!!
`               int asciiInt=0;
                foreach (char c in str[i])
                {
                    asciiInt = (int)c + asciiInt;
                }
                sum[i] = asciiInt; `

Comment: OMG~ it's ok now. IT seems that"label1.Text = sum.Length.ToString();" Have some problem.><  Anyway, thanks so much!!

Comment: Good to hear. If this answers your question you should mark it as accepted. The [faq] explains how. I'm letting you know this since I see you are new to Stack Overflow. Incidentally, welcome!!